# How to integrate QtMultimedia component into a project using CMake?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, cmake

I'm trying to write a GUI appication (under Ubuntu 18.04) using Qt5 and CMake. I failed to integrate the Qt multimedia module into my project.

My `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Chess)

#set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/mashplant/Qt5.9.6/5.9.6/gcc_64")
#whether I comment it off or not doesn't have an effect on the result

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets Network Multimedia REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(.)

add_executable(Main Main.cpp
    MainWindow.cpp MainWindow.hpp ChessFrame.cpp ChessFrame.hpp resource.qrc)

target_link_libraries(Main Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Network Qt5::Multimedia)
```

And I get the following warning when I run CMake:

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:18 (add_executable):
Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target Main because files in
some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit directories:

runtime library [libQt5Widgets.so.5] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
  /home/mashplant/Qt5.9.6/5.9.6/gcc_64/lib
runtime library [libQt5Network.so.5] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
  /home/mashplant/Qt5.9.6/5.9.6/gcc_64/lib
runtime library [libQt5Gui.so.5] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
  /home/mashplant/Qt5.9.6/5.9.6/gcc_64/lib
runtime library [libQt5Core.so.5] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
  /home/mashplant/Qt5.9.6/5.9.6/gcc_64/lib
Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.
```

And when I compile, I get a link error.

```
/home/mashplant/Qt5.9.6/5.9.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Multimedia.so.5.9.6：undefined reference to ‘operator delete(void*, unsigned long)@Qt_5’
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/Main.dir/build.make:203: recipe for target 'Main' failed
make[3]: *** [Main] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Main.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Main.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Main.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Main.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'Main' failed
make: *** [Main] Error 2
```

Comment: The problem is not with multimedia QT component, but with QT in general. You have 2 QT installed on your system: The system one, under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, and your own one, under `/home/mashplant/Qt5.9.6/5.9.6/gcc_64/lib`. But CMake cannot generate command line for the linker, so it could pick up proper QT installation. This is because libraries both from system and your directory are used in your project. If you want to use your QT installation, remove system-wide one. Do not forget to clear CMake cache (`CMakeCache.txt` file in build directory) before new attempts.

Comment: @Tsyvarev But in some previous projects without multimedia it works well. And that is why I want to know how to intergrate multimedia.

Comment: @MashPlant It might have worked by accident. I'd be really surprised if you didn't get the same warnings from CMake with those projects as well (even QtCore seems to conflict).  Can you try issuing CMake with this option `-DQt5_DIR=/home/mashplant/Qt5.9.6/5.9.6/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5`?

Answer (score 0):

My best bet is that CMake find different components from different installations of Qt. If that's the case, it should be enough to correct all Qt-related CMake variables to point to correct paths (for example, variables like `Qt5Widgets_DIR`, `Qt5Multimedia_DIR`, etc.).